# In C#, are for loops linear?

Tags: c#, overhead

Here I'm using the mathematical term for linear. If we look at, for example, the definition of averaging, we know that:

[image]

That's what I mean by linear. In C#, suppose I want to do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
{
    someVar[i] += i;
    someOtherVar[i] += i;
}
```

Does this cost the same overhead as:

```
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
{
    someVar[i] += i;
}
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
{
    someOtherVar[i] += i;
}
```

Would the difference change if the operation in the for loop is more complicated, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
{
    someOtherVar[i] *= Math.Cos(2.0 * Math.Pi * i / N);
}
```

Assume N is large, 16384 entries.

Comment: I don't think "C#" (which is a language, standardized) impose anything at this level of detail. Here is the standard for C# 5 by the way (the other versions are still at draft) : https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm . A lot of margin of appreciation is usually let to the compiler to do some optimization depending on the cases . I'm tempted to answer that you shouldn't assume anything in general about the overheads and the "cost" (whatever that means) of using one for loop vs 2 for loops.

Comment: Note that you can compile with different level of compiler optimization, this will lead to potentially different results, and thus "overhead" in your case. You can inspect the Intermediary Language (IL) produced by the compilation by using a tool like ILSpy

Comment: @Pac0 by "cost" I mean processor overhead. I was writing about a general case, my implementation will have between one and sixteen ops in the for loops, and I got curious about efficiency. I know C# isn't the most efficient language, but it's the language I'm forced to use.

Comment: I really think that you should not assume anything generally. We could examine your particular case, though, but I guess the content of the question is too simplified currently. I'd go for an empirical analysis.

Comment: I'd recommend always writing code that makes more logical sense than highly hand optimized. Using a tool like ILSpy @Pac0 or dnSpy will let you view the IL produced. dnSpy is also able reverse the stored IL and display it in C#. If you hover over the IL op codes it will tell you what they do.

Comment: @BenS.I really don't want for you to take this the wrong way it's not intended to be an insult, but you not knowing how for loops work will probably be a bigger issue in writing high performance code then any language you use.

Comment: @FilipCordas I know how for loops work. What I don't know is how compilers optimize things. This is a language-specific question about computational overhead.

Comment: @BenS. Again don't take this the wrong way but linear algebra is not something people need to optimize in 2020 there are so many libraries that can do this for you should not worry about this. If you want it really fast this is what graphic cards do, but again the numbers you are talking about are so small you can just buy a faster processor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as *complexity* goes, both a one and two loop algorithm are linear `O(n)` operations. But as far as actual *performance* (overhead), the two loop version is most likely slower. The compiler or runtime may opt to do optimizations, but two loops generally translate to:

```
set i to 0;

a:
if i < N goto done;
set someVar[i] = someVar[i] + i;
set i = i + 1
goto a;

done:
set i to 0;

b:
if i < N goto done;
set someOtherVar[i] = someOtherVar[i] + i;
set i = i + 1;
goto b;
```

...which is clearly more *steps* than one loop.

Comment: Sorry just interested did you actually compile this? This sort of stuff looks like it would be optimized by the compiler?

Comment: Actually, as to performance, when looking at the CPU level: if these are low-level arrays and not a clever abstraction, and the arrays are big enough, the two loop version *might* perform better due to fewer cache misses and the possibility of the CPU doing some predictive fetching. But at that level you never know until you measure the performance. And those results are likely only valid for that exact hardware...

Comment: @FilipCordas you do know that C# compiler does pretty much no optimizations (short of some basic expression evaluation and dead code removal)? Or your comment is about something different than "compile" (maybe JIT compilation?)

Comment: I didn't compile it, this is just pseudocode. My main point is if the algorithm requires more steps to complete, it's _generally_ slower. CPUs are sophisticated beasts, though, so @PontusGagge is correct. In fact, sometimes the CPU can even figure out that the two loops can be run in parallel since they aren't mutating the same areas of memory.

Comment: @PontusGagge indeed two loop version can perform better if written properly for two arrays - as long as optimization to remove boundary check is possible you should get noticable speedup... I doubt predictive fetching would give you much difference (but who knows without actually measuring)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov just general optimization I was thinking that it could be removed as dead code. Really should have just used ILSpy and tested my self.

Comment: @FilipCordas merging two loops can't be done by any compiler unless it can prove that there could be no side-effects of operations inside both loops... which in theory may be possible for C# with arrays, but for more complex types that implement own (possibly virtual) indexing it's basically out of the question. But C# compiler does not do anything like that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do (other languages do perform aggressive optimizations at compile time,  in .Net all real optimizations done at JIT compile time)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Absolutely right wasn't even thinking that this could be a custom indexer.

Answer (score 0):

I did an IL dump, and using one loop is faster than using two loops as there's the overhead incurred by incrementing "i".
That said, the difference will be minimal.

If you're dealing with a much larger data set and need to optimize this further, look into SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) operations.

https://habr.com/en/post/467689/

Comment: Note that looking at IL means almost absolutely nothing in relation to final performance of the code...

Comment: You're right that it's somewhat lacking as a performance measure, but it can still tell you which optimizations, if any, the compiler decided to make.